On VSCode, when using #%% cells, shift-enter no longer executes a cell in the interactive window and moves to the next cell
On VSCode, when using #%% cells, shift-enter no longer executes a cell in the interactive window and moves to the next cell. It used to work for many years, but now shift-enter on some line of code throws an error in a new window titled 'Python REPL'. I can still use control-enter to execute a cell in the interactive window, but that does not move the cursor to the next  cell. Could a VSCode update have changed the short-cut functionality?

"Could a VSCode update have changed the short-cut functionality?" - Yes. Or an extension update. Have you looked into that? like have you read any update notes, looked at your config, that sort of thing?

Have you tried troubleshooting keybindings?

Step 1:
Open Settings (Ctrl + .) and search for python.repl. Then disable:

python.REPL: Send to Native REPL

Step 2: Open keybindings.json by pressing Ctrl + Shift + P > Search for keyboard > Select Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON). Add or change shift + enter if already present:
  {
    "key": "shift+enter",
    "command": "-jupyter.runcurrentcelladvance",
    "when": "notebookCellListFocused && !interactiveEditorFocused && notebookCellType == 'code' || editorTextFocus && inputFocus && notebookEditorFocused && !interactiveEditorFocused"
  },

This when condition is copied from python.execInRepl command's keyboard shortcut which is taking over Shift + Enter

I tried using shift-enter in the new version of vscode, which executes cells in an interactive window. You can try updating your vscode version, or open the shortcut settings by typing the command Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts in the command palette. You can check if the Shift-Enter shortcut settings have changed, or create a new shortcut for executing cells in the interactive window. You can learn more about the shortcut settings in the document.

I also had the same problem, solution:
When you run Visual Studio Code, press Crtl + and search pyth rpl (See screenshot)
Make sure the two tabs are unchecked and restart VS Code.
See screenshot after restarting VS Code
